# Is it possible to create Azure alerts for multiple subscriptions at once?

Tags: azure-powershell

I am trying to create Alerts for different services on Azure but i need to create it for all subscriptions at once using PowerShell.

I have tried with GUI but failed.

Comment: No, you cannot. You just can do that via a script which changes the different subscriptions again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of subscriptions on the account it might take awhile, but you can pull an array of subscriptions from the account and perform the same actions on each of them in a loop. If you only want to run through certain subscriptions I would probably create a list in a csv file and then replace `az account list | ConvertFrom-Json` with the csv file.

```
$subs = az account list | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($sub in $subs) {
    az account set --subscription $sub.id
    "Current Account:"
    az account show

   # create alert 1
   # create alert 2
   # ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What columns should be included in the CSV?

Comment: What I'm extracting from the cli is just the subscription ID, which is all you need for this script. You might want to include a second column for the name in order to make it easier to tell which subs you are working with.